# Using a function to receive a vectorized output

Tags: r

I want to make a function in terms of x and coef for multiple values of x so that the output is a vector, like I've tried here:

```
directpoly<-function(x,coef) {
  for(n in length(coef)) {
    total<-sum(coef*x^(0:(n-1)))
  }
  total
}
```

This works when I input one value for x and any vector for the coefficient values, but I want more than that. I want to input a certain amount of values for the coefficients, say c(5,9,-2), and have the function produce three different values, one for each input of x for, say, x<-2:4. So in that case I'd want output 15, 14, 9. Any ideas? I am new so all help is appreciated.

Edit: I took out an "<-" that I accidentally put in there. Sorry if that was any cause for confusion. Also what I want in the end is a function 
P(x) = c1 + c2*x + ... + cn*x^n-1

Comment: `for(n in length(coef))`? what does this mean?? should you not have `for(n in seq_along(coef))`? or`for(n in 1:length(coef))`?

Comment: Can you edit your post to include an explanation on what you're trying to calculate? The statements in `directpoly` make no sense and/or are not valid R code.

Comment: `sapply(x,function(i,j)sum(j*i^(0:(length(j)-1))),coef)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this work?

```
directpoly <- function(x, coef) {
  seqcoef <- seq_along(coef) - 1
  sapply(x, function(z) sum(coef*z^seqcoef))
}

directpoly(2:4, c(5,9,-2))
# [1] 15 14  9
```

If so, the trick to solving this is two-steps:

1. Determine what you want to do with each value of `x` (no vector). In this case, it's simply from among:

   ```
   sum(coef*x^(1:length(coef)-1))
   sum(coef*x^(0:(length(coef)-1)))
   sum(coef*x^(seq_along(coef)-1))
   ```

   Because I'm eventually putting this into some loop/apply formulation, I don't need to recalculate the sequence each time, so I break it out:

   ```
   seqcoef <- seq_along(coef) - 1
   sum(coef*x^seqcoef)
   ```
2. Now that you know what to do *with each `x`*`, now map or apply over it:

   ```
   sapply(x, function(z) ...)
   ```

   where `...` is what we determined above. For clear coding, many believe the technique of hard-defining this function is good, so something like:

   ```
   directpoly1 <- function(x, coef, seqcoef = seq_along(coef) - 1) {
     sum(coef*x^seqcoef)
   }
   directpoly <- function(x, coef) {
     seqcoef <- seq_along(coef) - 1
     sapply(x, directpoly1, coef, seqcoef)
   }
   ```

   (I took a little more liberty with this version to enable running it explicitly with a scalar argument, primarily for unit-testing. It is not strictly necessary, so the function at the top of this answer should suffice.)

Comment: I am a new account so I can't upvote you but this absolutely worked and has helped me a lot, so thank you :)